# Why is there always isEmpty whereas I use !isEmpty 99% of the time

Tags: java

This question has bogged me quite a while. During programming there is regularly the question whether there is something in an object or not. For this reason was the `isEmpty` method invented. Great, but in practice we use it like `!isEmpty` almost all the time.

As a consequence, `notEmpty` would be a much more appreciated addition to a language like Java. The question is: why don't language designers think of this before defining the API? At least give a counterpart for `isEmpty`

EDIT: I meant there should be a `notEmpty` as well as `isEmpty`. Depending on the domain, both of them may be used but in most cases when a UI is not involved, I think `notEmpty` applies better.

EDIT2: To close the discussion, here is an example:

```
!metadata.isEmpty() == metadata.notEmpty()
```

I'd prefer we had the right side of the equation as well.

Comment: I don't agree with 99% part. I have used isEmpty almost 50% of the time while !isEmpty for the rest of the time.

Comment: Why not?  Just because you use `!isEmpty` doesn't mean every body else does...Personally, I think statement is more logical - IMHO

Comment: If anything, having a method name beginning with `is` is more consistent than one beginning with `not`.

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you are hoping for, this seems more like venting your opinion than asking a question.

Comment: I've voted to close - nobody here can answer this unless they were one of the original designers who did the *thinking*.

Comment: Using negative-assumptions would only cause confusion since pretty much everything else is the opposite.

Comment: I meant there should be a counterpart for isEmpty nd they should live in peace. It's much easier to mistate a `!` with the word `not` :)

Comment: Apparently, the vocabulary of the English language does not contain a word which would be the opposite of "empty", common enough for everyone to understand it, and less than 6 characters long. If there was such a a word, you may have had your wish fullfilled.

Comment: Surprised this has three re-open votes - it still seems to be a rant and/or a question about why the original API designers did things in a particular way.

Comment: Maybe someone has more insight into the "birth" of the isempty method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isEmpty` follows the naming convention of other syntactically positive `isXXX` methods such as [isVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isVisible%28%29) and [isEnabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isEnabled%28%29)

Comment: Bah, I should have posted my comment as an answer :P

Comment: I appreciate your opinion @AlexMDC.

Comment: Yeah, but you could find a positive word which means not empty. Like `isGotSomethingInIt` but grammatical. Or do we think that we have this negative concept in positive lexical clothes purely because the English language has no simple word for nonempty?

Comment: Why not `isNotEmpty()` then?

Comment: @svz Probably due to convention: we don't say `isNotVisible`

Comment: @TomAnderson youve probably answered your own question there. Its probably easier a) because `empty` is a short word that describes exactly the object state and b) its more logical to think in terms of positives and negate as necessary

Comment: @Reimeus: Except that 'empty' isn't semantically a positive. It's only syntactically a positive. That could be the root of this oddity. It is interesting but sad if that is the case.

Answer (score 4):

I think it follows the convention of using `is[Something]()` for booleans in place of `get[Something]()`.

Also, having to use `!notEmpty()` might get a bit confusing!

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is, it is more logical because like `==` and `!=`. Logically It is better to have `isEmpty` and `!isEmpty`, It is easy to understand.