# How to clear result in string array Android/Java

Tags: java, android

After finding a word in a sentence, I want to the user to be able to clear his entries and type again a sentence in the edittext.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
 final String[] words = {"cowboy", "animal"};
 final String[] meanings = { "meaning1", "meaning2" };
 Boolean check = false;

 private void initControls() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    text = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);

    view = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

    clear = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);

    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text.setText("");
            view.setText("");
        }
    });

    ok = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            findAmbiguousWord();
        }   
    });
}

private void findAmbiguousWord(){
    String string = text.getText().toString();

    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (string.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
            check = true;
            index = i;
        } 
    }

    view.setText(check ? meanings[index] : "No ambiguous word/s found.");
}
```

When I tried to clear my entry and typed again new entry, the same result was displaying. what should be done to avoid displaying the previous result? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that when you click on the clear button, the text in the `TextView` is not cleared?

Comment: You have to use addTextChangeListener for edittext. It will works. thanks.

Comment: @SharifurRahman In what way would a TextChangedListener help here?

Comment: Just one thing, I think you might want to have `int index = -1;` or have `view.setText(check ? meanings[index] : "No ambiguous word/s found.");
}` inside the `if` condition. Also have an `else` statement there. I am saying this as it might be that you never enter the `if` condition when there is no substring of that type and then the result always is the word at `meanings[0]` as index is 0. Try that.

Comment: I think the EditText value is not getting reset !, an idea would be getting value of EditText onclick on button1; and passing the String to FindAmbigousWords; instead of working on a global Edittext.

Comment: Don't use a field (`check`) for storing the computation result like this. Create a function that returns whether the check is successful or not and make this computation depend only on the input parameters, no hidden dependency like this `check` field. Avoid mutable state as much as you can, it will again and again spoil your code.

Comment: @RachitMishra can you give me a sample to do that?

Comment: @allprog hi I'm new to Java I don't know the best practice approach for this. Can you give me sample code to do that?

Comment: heyy you code work okay, i.e if i type hey cowboy, it gives meaning1; reset & if i type hey animal, it gives meaning2

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I tried to change index to -1 but when no ambiguous words, logcat throws arrayoutofboundsexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the checking functionality to a method like this:

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        checkAmbiguousWord();
    }   
});  

...

private void checkAmbiguousWord(){
    final String textToCheck = text.getText().toString();
    Integer ambiguousIndex = findAmbiguousWordIndex(textToCheck);
    view.setText(ambiguousIndex != null ? meanings[ambiguousIndex] : "No ambiguous word/s found.");
}

/**
 * @param text checked for ambguous words
 * @return the index of the ambiguous word in the {@code words} array or
 * null if no ambiguous word is found
 */
private Integer findAmbiguousWordIndex(String text) {
    final String lowerCasedText = text.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (lowerCasedText.contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This eliminates the dependence on a hidden internal state (the `check` variable). This programming style allows you to separate the view controller code and the business functionality and eventually write tests for the business functionality independently from the views.

UPDATE: to show multiple ambiguous words, use a list for the indexes

```
private void checkAmbiguousWord(){
    final String textToCheck = text.getText().toString();
    List<Integer> ambiguousIndexes = findAmbiguousWordIndexes(textToCheck);
    view.setText(!ambiguousIndexes.isEmpty() ? ambigousIndexesToMessage(ambiguousIndexes) : "No ambiguous word/s found.");
}

    public String ambigousIndexesToMessage(List<Integer> ambiguousIndexes) {
        // create the text using the indexes
        // this is an example implementation
        return ambiguousIndexes.toString(); // creates a list of "1","2",...
    }

/**
 * @param text checked for ambguous words
 * @return the list of indexes of the the ambiguous words in the {@code words} array          
 */
private List<Integer> findAmbiguousWordIndexes(String text) {
    final String lowerCasedText = text.toLowerCase();
    final List<Integer> ambiguousWordIndexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (lowerCasedText.contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
            ambiguousWordIndexList.add(i);
        }
    }
    return ambiguousWordIndexList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I can better understand it. Anyways, can it allow spaces?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? The `String.contains()` method looks for a substring in a string. It doesn't consider spaces or other delimiters, just chcecks if the input substring is present in the string you called the `contains()` on.

Comment: Hi I got question again, what if I type more than one word in the array, it only displays the first word it fetches. How can I display the other words?

Comment: Added example. Basically you need to use a list for the indexes. Note that the message constructor method implementation is a really basic one. I trust you can write whatever you want :)

Comment: Okay but in your added example, when I tried to input two words, it gave me no ambiguous words

Comment: My bad, I forgot to negate the isEmpty() call. This is the exact reason I asked a question a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271427/why-is-there-always-isempty-whereas-i-use-isempty-99-of-the-time You can upvote it and have one more scream for better programming languages :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36268/discussion-between-dunkey-and-allprog)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the check to false at start of method.